# How to ignore an extension file in entire app except a particular folder

Tags: github

I have a requirement in my project where I need to ignore the `.html` file to track via git in the project however need to track any `.html` file in a given folder along with its sub folder.

I tried using below code to exclude to track all files from `ignore_directory` but it didn't worked.

```
*.html

!ignore_directory/*
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the correct way to exclude a directory.

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor or
# operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global

*.html

!ignore_directory/*
```

Either the path you have is incorrect or is not relative to the directory you want to exclude. It's also possible that the directory you want to exclude contains a gitignore file overriding your exclusion.

Read [GitHub help on Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/en/articles/ignoring-files) for a simple introduction to ignoring files and also tead the [Git - gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).